# Description of projective $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$-modules

Tags: group-cohomology, projective-module, group-rings

I am working my way through Ken Browns [book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9327-6) on the cohomology of groups, and in particular chapters 8 and 9 on finiteness conditions, and Euler characteristics.

Most of the concepts in chapter 9 (such as the Hattori-Stallings rank) are defined (initially) in terms of finitely generated projective $\mathbb{Z} G$-moudles, and one thing that I am struggling with in general is what these (non-free) projective $\mathbb{Z} G$-modules look like for different groups $G$.

For instance, in the case of a finite group the projective $\mathbb{Z} G$-modules were classified by [Swan](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1959-65-06/S0002-9904-1959-10376-1/S0002-9904-1959-10376-1.pdf): any projective $\mathbb{Z} G$-module is the direct sum of a free module and an ideal $I\le \mathbb{Z} G$.

However, the groups I am interested in are not finite: the case that would be of initial interest is $G=\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.

So what can be said about projective $\mathbb{Z} [\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})]$-modules?

I am also interested in the general case when $G\le\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a finite index subgroup (say a [principal congruence subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#Congruence_subgroups)), but here I am guessing that the projective modules over $G$ will be related to those over $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ using some standard homological algebra.

I have seen some other papers about resolutions over linear group rings ([1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2011.09.018)), and projective modules over group rings for some groups ([2](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/14.2.124), [3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(71)90091-3)) but I haven't found anything explicitly for the case $G\le\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ which is what I was hoping for.

Any help, comments, or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are right this is way too vague of a question.
The use of this information is to understand the construction of the Euler characteristic of groups, but also to study projective resolutions of $\mathbb{Z} G$-modules and the associated syzygy modules. 
So, I guess that what I am wanting is even just an example of the construction of a projective module. I know that $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely presented so can I for instance use this presentation to construct a projective module explicitly?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks a lot this looks very helpful!